# hasNextDouble(), my program stops without crashing and without looping

Tags: java

My program seems stuck in the middle of my while loop, without crashing and without looping infinitely. It just stops.
The loop runs for as many input as the user provides, but then does not move on the the next line of code.
It is my first time using the hasNextDouble() in java. Am I doing it right?

Here is the while loop in question:

```
System.out.print("Grades (separated by a space)");
while(in.hasNextDouble())
{
    student1.addGrade(in.nextDouble());
}
```

And here is a little bit more of my code:

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = "";
    Student student1 = new Student();
    GradeBook book = new GradeBook();

    // Sets the name of the first student
    System.out.print("Name: ");
    input = in.nextLine();
    student1.setNames(input);

    // Sets the grades of the first student
    System.out.print("Grades (separated by a space)");
    while(in.hasNextDouble()){
        student1.addGrade(in.nextDouble());
    }

    // Put the student into the GradeBook
    book.addStudent(student1);

    // Prints the report
    System.out.print(book.reportGrades());
```

Comment: Scanner can't assume that there will be no more input as long as System.in is not closed which is why `in.hasNextDouble()` needs to wait for any input, or for closing stream signal. To exit from loop provide non-double value like "finish".

Comment: thanks for the explanation Pshema, that makes sense. adding any other input at the end of the sequence works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You state you want space separated input, in a single line. I would suggest taking the input as a `String`, and then splitting it up, like

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String line = in.nextLine();
for(String s : line.split(" ")){
    student1.addGrade(Double.parseDouble(s)); //gives exception if value is not double
}
```

`Scanner.hasNextDouble` will continue to return `true`, until you enter a non-Double value.

Answer (score 0):

With hasNext() you check if there is anything, then with hasNextDouble() check if the next input can be cast to double. You read the value with next(), but the value is still a string, so you need to parse it to double.

Also, you need a way to get out of the loop with break when input is no longer a number.

```
while (in.hasNext()) {
    if (in.hasNextDouble()) {
        student1.add(Double.parseDouble(in.next()));
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```